# How to access accessibility settings in MacOSX Cocoa app using swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, permissions

I'm pretty confused. Usually in an iOS app I would access the settings using a url scheme. Now I found out that on MacOSX using Objective-C you can do this:

```
    NSDictionary *options = @{(id)kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt: @YES};
    BOOL accessibilityEnabled = AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions((CFDictionaryRef)options);
```

I've tried to convert this to Swift but didn't got to a valid result.
Does anyone know how to convert this or a valid method to ask for assistive access in Swift?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt` type is `Unmanaged<CFString>` so you need to access to the retained value as show below

```
let options : NSDictionary = [kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt.takeRetainedValue() as NSString: true]
let accessibilityEnabled = AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions(options)
```