# How can I set accessibility preferences from Swift app?

Tags: swift, accessibility

I took a look at [How to access accessibility settings in MacOSX Cocoa app using swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36258866/how-to-access-accessibility-settings-in-macosx-cocoa-app-using-swift), and checking the setting makes my app ask for it.

Running from the XCode simulator prompts:

[image: Accessibility Access Prompt]

Is there a way to make the System Preferences automatically check the app? As of now, I have to unlock them, and then check the app.